# How can we use the dynamically upload images effectively and responsively in content management system like Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal-7, content-management-system

Need Solution for the following:

- single image uploaded via cms to be used responsively without losing
  clarity...and also bigger file size images being used in devices.
- methods that can be done to improve faster loading of image files and overall site performance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the picture module https://www.drupal.org/project/picture. You need to set it up using breakpoints but it should be able to take care of both of your issues. The picture module creates variation of your image for different breakpoints.

Comment: I have heard of <picture> element recently added to the HTML specification, but haven't tried of drupal picture module. While going through the module link its seen that picture module has been added as core for drupal 8.

Comment: I just tried to implement the picture module in drupal 7, one thing is that initial setting of breakpoints and for each image style that we use its a bit process to be done and also about the dependency module - breakpoints that to be added for the working of picture module. I started looking more on the picture module  to know whether it satisfy my requirements..anyway thanks for the solution.